# How to check what White Balance setting was used (on a Mac)?

Tags: software, metadata, apple-aperture, white-balance

I've been experimenting with different white balance settings, and I can see what was used while browsing photos on my Nikon preview screen.

But when I copy the photos to my laptop where I can examine them more carefully, I have no way of looking up which WB setting was used. I have aperture, and that does show some info about the shot (ISO, Shutter speed, lens, zoom) but it also doesn't say anything about WB setting.

Would I need a special utility? Or is there a way to do it in Apple Aperture?

I am using Nikon D7000 (jpeg images), and a laptop using OSX Lion.

Comment: It should be available in the 'Meta' tab methinks.

Comment: "my laptop" is not a program that I am familiar with. And "my nikon" is not a camera model I have heard of. The tags suggest you are using Photoshop and an Apple but that may be a further part of the plot. Most cameras will record white-balance setting in the EXIF data. Most photo viewing and manipulation programs will allow you to view the EXIF data and there are numerous free programs which will allow you to view and/or manipulate EXIF data.

Comment: As @VaishakSuresh said, look at the "Metadata" tab between "Library" and "Adjustments", and you will find it.  For example, I see my last woodpecker picture was taken with the "Cloudy weather" white balance setting.  If you don't see the Library/Metadata/Adjustment tab set, hit "i" to show your info panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok! I went back and checked. Here is how you will see the white balance. The Bulb icon before JPEG and after Camera Name is your white balance.

[image: Aperture on Mac]

Comment: We will have to see what he says!  I use a Canon as well, and see white balance descriptions nicely, but perhaps Dudeist is implying that Nikon is different?  Also: I have more than just the bulb icon on my Metadata tab.  Midway down the Metadata pane under EXIF Info, my display truly says:  "White Balance: Cloudy weather".

Comment: @khedron I have a Nikon too and it works similarly for me.

Comment: nice! but how did you get to that dialog ? i tried right clicking and "get info" which shows some info about the exposure, but not this screen

Comment: ahh i googled around , and this is Aperture! yep.. i can see it there the same. thanks!

Comment: wow! that tab even shows me which of the 39 focus points was used!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the precise temperature and tint, you can see that in the *White Balance* adjustment. When importing a raw image file, even though the adjustment is not active, the sliders will default to the actual white balance set by the camera.

This can be handy when the camera has an Auto white balance.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am wrong, but. In exif, you have only basic info. For White Balance only AUTO or Preset. If you need more info, you can read it only from RAW file, for Nikon NRW. I am Windows user, but I am sure, for Mac is free ViewNX 2 too.
 Run it, find your NRW photo. Now you can see only basic EXIF info. Click **Edit** icon. Now you can adjust or/and check color balance. For jpg files, you can check settings too, but you can't edit it.